# Dropdown menu on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I need to make a simple dropdown menu to my rails app, but all i can find is dropdown selects.
does any1 know a good guide on making dropdown menus? just a simple menus, nothing fancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropdown menu is not something that is built in rails and you need a javascript plugin to achieve that.

If you are using [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) as your javascript framework in your rails app, here are some of [prototype+scriptaculous based dropdown menu plugin](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=prototype+dropdown+menu) . If you are using jQuery as your javascript framework in your rails framework, here are some of [jQuery based dropdown menu plugin](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=jquery+dropdown+menu).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I found this little script called jdMenu, it uses jquery i think, and it worked great, ty for the help